# How to map JSON data into any Object in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, object, dictionary, jersey

I would like to map from JSON-Response into my Java Object using Jersey. I have this such Json response:

```
{
  "act": "add",
  "col": "student",
  "data": [
  {
     "firstName": "alex",
     "lastName": "homer",
     "age": "18",
     "roomNo": "1301"
  },
  {
     "firstName": "alex",
     "lastName": "homer",
     "age": "18",
     "roomNo": "1301"
  }
  ]
}
```

And this is my bean that I'd like to map the Json-response into:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RequestAction implements RequestOperations {

   @XmlElement(required = true, name = "act")
   private String action;

   @XmlElement(required = true, name = "col")
   private String collectionName;

   @XmlElement(required = false, name = "oid")
   private String objectId;

   @XmlElement(name = "data")
   private List<Object> data;

   public RequestAction() {
}

//getters setters
}
```

So, my problem is how to map data under `"data": {[....]}`?
Because it also can be identified with any `Object`.

For this example, the object is `Customer`. How about if object is `Student`, `Animal`, or anything else? If possible, I dont need create that object (I means `Customer`, and others).
Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: 'How about if object is Student, Animal, or anything else.' This will not work. You must use classes more specific than `Object`.

Comment: if its going to be anything then i guess you should use a Map to contain all values.

Comment: Sikorski, you mean using Map<String, String> field = new HashMap<>() like this ?

Comment: If all data is of same type, just specify the type. Otherwise, find a common denominator (interface or abstract class), and make all classes that can go in data to extend / implement this super-type.

Comment: Take a look at the Jackson polymorphic deserialization: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Answer (score 0):

Consider use of Gson library: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
I didn't have a problem with lists there.

Answer (score -1):

if your bean property name are the same as your JSON's, you can use json-lib.
For maven project, just put

`<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
     <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
 </dependency>`

into the pom.xml.

`JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(YOUR JSON STRING);
 RequestAction re = (RequestAction) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject,RequestAction.class);`

Comment: 'if your bean property name are the same as your JSON's' That is not the case because there are no properties of `Object` to map `firstName` or `lastName` to.

Comment: if the List element is Object ,this code will put net.sf.ezmorph.bean.MorphDynaBean into list.
you can create a new bean named data to put firstName lastName, in that way ,you need change code into `Map classMap = new HashMap();
        classMap.put("data", Data.class);
        RequestAction re = (RequestAction) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject,RequestAction.class);`